# Javascript/JQuery Value not setting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I've been trying different techniques to get my value to be set through the placeholder "Card number", but nothing seems to be working. Even when I attempt to use normal JavaScript I get the error that document.querySelector is null.

```js
$('[data-card-field-placeholder*="Card"]').val('2222');
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field__input-wrapper field__input-wrapper--icon-right"><label class="field__label field__label--visible" for="checkout_credit_card_number">Card number</label>
          <div class="field__input field__input--iframe-container" data-card-fields="number" data-card-field-placeholder="Card number" aria-describedby="error-for-number tooltip-for-number"><iframe class="card-fields-iframe" id="card-fields-number-fzjcuxuv2z000000" name="card-fields-number-fzjcuxuv2z000000" scrolling="no" src="" style="height: 43px;" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
            <span id="credit_card_number_tooltip" class="field__icon icon icon--lock">
    <span class="visually-hidden">Secure field</span>
  </span>

        </div>
```

Comment: To me it looks like you want to update some `input` that's within that iframe.  It might not be possible.  I would look for a solution within the API you're using.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `text()` instead of `val()`. Like this:

```js
$('[data-card-field-placeholder*="Card"]').text('2222');
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field__input-wrapper field__input-wrapper--icon-right"><label class="field__label field__label--visible" for="checkout_credit_card_number">Card number</label>
          <div class="field__input field__input--iframe-container" data-card-fields="number" data-card-field-placeholder="Card number" aria-describedby="error-for-number tooltip-for-number"><iframe class="card-fields-iframe" id="card-fields-number-fzjcuxuv2z000000" name="card-fields-number-fzjcuxuv2z000000" scrolling="no" src="" style="height: 43px;" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
            <span id="credit_card_number_tooltip" class="field__icon icon icon--lock">
    <span class="visually-hidden">Secure field</span>
  </span>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use '.attr()' instead instead of '.val()'. '.val' is for setting form elements values, whereas '.attr()' is for setting attributes.

```
$('[data-card-field-placeholder*="Card"]').attr('data-card-field-placeholder', '2222');
```

More info:

- [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)
- [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)